# Optimal path around a variable-position wall

Tags: mathematics, optimization

This is a harder version of [the fixed wall variation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30947/magic-wall-force-field-obstructed-walk-what-is-minimal-average-path).

Every day you walk across a flat plane from a point $A$ to a point $B$.  The points are $3$ miles apart.  However, every day there is a 50% chance that there is an invisible force field between the two points.  The force field extends $1$ mile in each direction perpendicular to the line between $A$ and $B$, and its position is uniformly distributed between the two points.  You don't know if the force field is present or where it is until you run into it.

**What path should you take to minimize the distance you must travel to reach point $B$ from point $A$ on average?**  This a mathematical problem, so your solution shouldn't involve "lateral thinking," like climbing over the wall.  You can assume that you can follow your planned path exactly, the wall has negligible thickness, etc.

---

Computer simulation might be a good way to try to solve this but mathematical solutions are encouraged as well.

I am not good at drawing out diagrams here to show the possible paths so I hope someone can add it to their answer.

The answer could be expressed as an angle to leave starting point $A$; I am not sure how else the answer can be expressed other than maybe total distance traveled on average.

How the hell can this be off topic when the previous simpler version of this was not?  Whoever stated it is off topic is very inconsistent and also this question received 2 upvotes and 3 favorite votes so it would make sense to keep it open and active, not on hold.  Please "fix" this ASAP.

Comment: is the position of the wall uniformly randomly distributed on the segment with endpoints A and B?

Comment: Yes the wall can be ANY random position between and B so any position within those $3$ miles.  It could be $1$ inch away or $2.99999$ miles away or any position in between A and B.  I guess on average it will be $1.5$ miles away.

Comment: Something tells me that since the average distance the wall will be away is $1.5$ miles, that an optimal solution should be based on that assumption as if the wall was fixed at that location.  However, the answer may surprise us and not be that.

Comment: it's clear that it can be in any position between them, and on average it's at halfway. but is the _distribution_ uniform? normal? anything else satisfying these conditions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean is the distribution uniform/normal.  Imagine a random number between 0 and 3 being generated for each walk and that is the position along the AB path that the invisible wall is set at.  Whatever properties a purely random number has, those are the same properties the wall position will have.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: For a computer simulation, just generate a random wall position between 0 and 3 miles (can be any fraction such as $2.1415926535$... miles) and then you would have to try many different angles to walk from starting from point A (0 degrees would be directly at B).  I may try to write this simulation program eventually.

Comment: I guess that means uniform (chance of every position is the same)

Comment: Yes but you don't have to wear a uniform when traversing the path.  You can have shorts and a t-shirt and a beer in one hand that is acceptable ha ha.  Good luck solving it, this seems non-trivial.

Comment: @David James, there are many ways to generate a random position which satisfy the conditions you set. 'purely random' is not a mathematical idea, I'm afraid. (just ask mathematicians if a normal distribution is purer than a uniform or not.) probably you are thinking of a uniform distribution, where the probability of the wall being x close to A is linear with x. is that a right assumption?

Comment: @David James, as you are referring to widely available pseudo-random-generators, it seems you are indeed thinking of the position being uniformly distributed. could you please add this important detail to the original question? thanks! it's a challenging problem, indeed, I like it!

Comment: Someone else please change the question to include this uniformity discussed here as they can probably word it better than me.  I normally assume that a random number will have the properties of any wall position being equally likely each walk.  If it simplifies things at all, we can assume that the wall position can only be at 1/10 mile positions (such as 0.1, 0.2, ... 2.8, 2.9) but if that complicates things then we can leave it out.  I am not a mathematician so I don't know if that would make it harder or easier but I suspect it wont change the answer much.

Comment: this may be the optimal path (probably not), but I lack the information and the time to get the math together, anyway you may shout by time to time and when you hear yourself you know that the wall is approcing, then you start turning and go around the wall. if the wall is too close to do echo, then you' ll end up against it, but the chanche of that happening is preatty low anyway.

Comment: @Jackyz, "lateral" thinking is not allowed as stated in the edited question.  Normally I try to do this too but in this question it is disallowed.  There is no indication of the wall position until you actually hit it, at which point you stop immediately and since there is no backtracking your path, you can assume you do not pass the wall at all and have to take any steps backwards.

Comment: ops, i missed the "no-lateral-thinking" part, my bad :) !

Comment: @DavidJames While I didn't vote to close this one, I agree with the vote. Note that the only way to solve this is to use integrals, differential equations and the Euler-Lagrange formula, all things which are firmly into higher education math level, while the other one was much simpler: you just needed to observe that the optimal path is a line.

Comment: I disagree.  Why should a more difficult but related puzzle be put on hold?  Just reclassify it where it should be.  Also I disagree those are the only methods to solve.  Computer simulation of "walking" many routes can easily assist in finding the shortest path on average.   I doubt it would be always walking a straight line segment from A to B then just walking around the wall and continuing diagonally to B.  I think this can be shown easily just by taking a few examples such as wall positions at $0.5$ miles, $1$ mile, $1.5$ miles (the midpoint between A and B), $2$ miles, and $2.5$ miles.

Comment: I looked at both the questions and all the answers, and I don't feel like it should be closed this soon. Yes, it does involve good level mathematics, as in the given answer, but it can be simulated (as stated) so adding a better tag would suffice.

Comment: I voted to close both. Being simulable does not make this a puzzle, and if 2012rcampion's answer is correct, a simulation as you propose wouldn't find the right path anyway.

Comment: @David James, let me start with that I don't want to sound offensive. I still feel a high level of ambiguity around the question, as all your comments and answers seem to be about another problem, which is: 'given a fixed position, where the wall appears with 50%, what is the optimal path? and how does this path change with where this fixed position is?' - kind of like a parametric, but definitely not stochastic problem. as the question was finally rephrased by someone else, maybe you meant it another way? might this be the source of all the confusion?

Comment: @David James, regarding the question of how a generalized version of an earlier problem might fall into a 'math problem'-category, while the original was only a 'brain teasing puzzle': probably you know the puzzle where two-colored prisoners sitting behind each other have to guess the color of their own hat. while this can be solved by the well-known everyday idea of parity, it has several variations which are more and more challenging, and getting into deep mathematics. some of them only need modular arithmetic, but the hardcore version's solution uses the axiom of choice. [to be continued]

Comment: @David James [cont.] as you introduced the randomness, the solution needed some analytic calculus. even worse, the actual problem turned out to be solvable only with tools known from the field of differential equations. even though I did not vote to 'close because of being off-topic', I can understand, why others did so. it just turned out, that this generalization needs heavy math apparatus to be solved. I don't even think there is an easier way to get to the solution, as the final answer itself was really complex.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not the optimal strategy, but at least a full discussion of a strategy, namely the 'try to go from A to B on a straight line, and if the wall appears, walk to its end, and walk straight from there to B' strategy.

So there's 50% chance that the path will be $3$ miles long, and 50% chance it will be not a straight line. In that case $x$ will be any distance you walked until you bumped into a wall. The remaining distance is on the AB-axis is $3-x$. You have to walk $1$ mile to circumvent the wall.

So straight line path: $3$ miles.
Random wall (at mile $x$) path: $x + 1 + \sqrt{1^2 + (3-x)^2}$

Example:
Wall occurs at $1.78$ miles.
Path length: $1.78 + 1 + \sqrt{1^2 + (3-1.78)^2} \approx 4.35$ miles.

With the wall being placed uniformly randomly on the $3$ mile, the average distance with this strategy is
$\frac12\cdot3+\frac12\frac{\int_0^3x+1+\sqrt{1+(3-x)^2}\mathrm{d}x}3\approx3.69$ miles

Comment: But you dont have to walk straight from A to B, you can walk at an angle starting from A such as slightly north or slightly south.  If the wall was at a fixed location such as the 1.5 mile position, the optimal solution (minimal distance) would NOT be walking straight from A to B until you hit the wall.  Walking diagonal would be a shorter path.

Comment: You're making no sense, you clearly stated multiple times, "The wall position will not be known until you actually bump it and can be anywhere between A and B and will extend 1 mile in both directions perpendicular to the AB path.". If the position is not known the direct path if obviously the most efficient, especially if you have a 50% chance of getting a straight path.

Comment: See this related problem with the restriction of having a fixed position wall midway between A and B.  The optimal solution is NOT walking directly from A to B it is walking diagonal from A to about midway up (or down) the wall. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30947/magic-wall-force-field-obstructed-walk-what-is-minimal-average-path

Comment: @Coma, I'm afraid the calculation for the wall path with your strategy is not correct: Y=3-X, so it should be 1.78 + 1 + sqrt(1^2+(3-1.78)^2) = 4.35 miles

Comment: @DavidJames, sure, but your modification of that problem means, that a strategy which was optimal for the fixed-position case is not necessarily optimal for a random-position one. and you still did not clarify the actual distribution of the position.

Comment: I think that knowing the wall position will (on average) be about 1.5 miles away from starting point A, that implies that the optimal path will NOT be walking directly from A to B then just walking around the wall, although that is a good starting point to integrate and then try to beat.

Comment: $3.6918$ miles on average for a random position wall but that is if you walk straight towards B initially (from A) then walk around the wall and diagonally to B but I doubt that is the optimal path.  Just try a few random wall points (such as at distance $0.5$, $1.5$, and $2.5$ miles) but with a "launch" angle up from A instead.  I will simulate this on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Rough outline of an answer:

I'm going to assume the optimal answer is in the same format as the original question: that is, we walk upwards up to a height of X, then downwards until the end, circumventing the wall whenever we find it (I'm using 'upwards' and 'downwards' in terms of a 2D diagram perspective, in real life 'left' and 'right').

In half the time, there is no wall, and we walk sqrt(x^2 + 1.5^2) as per in the original question.

25% of the time, the wall will show up on our upwards path, on average at the 0.75 mark. In this case, we walk towards X until we reach the wall, then go around it and head downwards the rest of the way.

The remaining 25% of the time the wall will show up on our downwards path, on average at the 2.25 mark. In this case we walk towards X, begin our way down, then go around it and head to the end.

then all that's left is to model the simple geometry and optimize for X.

Comment: I tested this solution, and it gets within about 1% of what I got for the optimal solution.  My guess is that you could do even better by varying the horizontal position of point X.

Comment: The wall is symmetrical with respect to the AB direct path.  That is, it will extend 1 mile "up" and 1 mile "down" so it doesn't matter if you leave A with either an "up" or "down" angle as you will hit the wall at the same distance away from A since it is symmetrical.

Answer (score -1):

My solution would involve computer simulation only using a reasonable number of random wall positions (or equally spaced wall positions).  For example, I can try wall positions $0.1$ miles from A, $0.2, 0.3... 2.8, 2.9$.  To those $29$ points I can try multiple launch angles from A to the wall.  That should get me an answer reasonably close to optimal.  If the runtime of the program is reasonable I can increase the number of "slices" of the 3 mile distance to more than just $29$ and increase the # of launch angles too.

Comment: Why would someone downvote a computer simulation?  That is a valid solution method and a reasonable approximation.

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting, but this description seems to be quite vague for me. What is an actual strategy? Is it going in a straight line starting with some $\alpha$ angle? What do you do if there is no wall? I think you should remember, that the strategy could not be chosen according to the actual position of the wall (it is suggested by your words 'launch angles from A to the wall', that you do this), but on the contrary: all the wall positions have to be tested for a given strategy.

Comment: The program would just try multiple angles leaving from A for random wall positions and choose the best on average.  For example, I could try 1 degree, 2 degrees, 3 degrees... and maintain an accumulated total distance walked using those angles and then just choose the best (shortest path) when I am all done.  The limit of the angle would be such that I wouldn't "overshoot" the wall in  the case where the wall is close to the full 3 miles away from A.  Seems like a fairly simple simulation program to write using a general purpose language.  I might try it.

Comment: I calculated that if you keep the "leave" angle from A no more than $18.4$ degrees ($.3218$ radians),  then you will never "overshoot" the wall even if it is all the way down close to the $3$ mile distance at B.  Since we know the rise and run of the wall at a point very close to B, we can use a maximum rise of $1$ mile and a run of about $3$ miles and ask for the a arctangent of that and we get about $18.4$ degrees.

Comment: I think it's an important question, that if you left A with, for example 12 degrees, and now you've done 2.8 miles (projected to the AB path), if that should raise your suspicion, that 'maybe we are in that 50%, when the wall did not appear', and it's worth risking turning straight towards B. or would you still keep going straight, until you reach a point which is on the same line as B, perpendicular to the AB path?

Comment: I think that's important to notice: as you are getting further on the AB path without hitting the wall, the chances that there is not wall at all are raising.

Comment: That is why this question should be reinstated cuz the optimal solution is not obvious at all.  It may be that a certain angle is not optimal but rather, an arc such that as you traverse the AB path more and more, you curve your path to a lower angle, anticipating that the wall is not present.  This would be more difficult to simulate on a computer but would be something like leave A at $18.4$ degrees up angle, and gradually decrease that angle as you get past the midway point (the 1.5 mile mark).  The solution might be a combination of choosing the optimal angle(s) and probability of wall.

Comment: Another useful comment is that if the wall was fixed at the midpoint of AB which is at $1.5$ miles from both A and B, it has already been computed that the optimal leave angle from A is such that you will reach slight over midpoint up the wall ($0.53$ miles I think) to minimize the walk distance on average.  So a starting  solution for the variable wall would be to  make it so the leave angle makes the walk path pass thru the middle of the wall if it was at the $1.5$ mile position, therefore never overshooting the wall if it is say at the $2.9$ mile position.